# how to place image with text under it on the corner of the page

Tags: miktex, texmaker

i am using the below latex code to place an image on the right corner of the page. but i do not know how to add some text below the image.
i want the text to be under the image and both on the right corner of the page

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt]  at (current page.north east)
{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{rsz_fh_logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

please let me know how to do that

Comment: with the `stackengine` package, you can `\stackunder{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{rsz_fh_logo}}{My text is here}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `label` in a TikZ node.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, label={[text width=4cm]below:My text is here, my very very long long text is here.}] (img) at (current page.north east)
{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you..but now , the label of the image is about 6 words, and when i use your code, only three words appear while the other disappear.i tried to use \\ to split the label across the lines but did not work. how to split the lable

Comment: @Elpharaoh See edit. You can align the text differently by adding `align=center` after the `text width=` command, for example.

Comment: thank you..but can i leave margin from the right  and from the top of the image? how to do it please

Comment: @Elpharaoh If you're loading the `calc` library, then you can say: `... at ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-1cm)$)`, for example.